# How to detect the end and start-point of an edge with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

i really want to know what the best way of detecting and extracting the start and end-point of an edge is, if i got images like this, with different angles of the black material.

[image]

[image]

I found some ideas which are using a gaussian blur and the canny-operator for detecting the edges. But i also want to extract the exact pixel postion of the first and last point. It would be really awesome if anyone can told me the correct step by step concept for accomplishing this task.

Comment: Maybe `cvFindContours` first, then take the points on the contour at minimum x and maximim x? Only really suitable for that example image though!

Comment: Why don't you use the blur to find the edges and then use the original image to find the pixel accurate position?

Comment: It would help if you clarified the assumptions you can make.  In your example image the only colours are black and white.  There is also only 1 edge.  The resulting line you labeled is straight and extends all the way across the image.  Will all of those things always be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your pictures are similar to the one you have posted (i.e. all edges intersect the top and left side of the image), the following simple program finds the top-right column and bottom-left row number of the edge:

```
cv::Mat im, edge, locs;
im = cv::imread("./lBnUO.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Canny(im, edge, 0.0, 255.0);
cv::findNonZero(edges(cv::Range(0, 1), cv::Range(0, edge.cols)), locs);
int topRightCol = (locs.at<cv::Point>(0)).x;
cv::findNonZero(edges(cv::Range(0, edge.rows), cv::Range(0, 1)), locs);
int bottomLeftRow = (locs.at<cv::Point>(0)).y;
std::cout << "Top-right point column: " << topRightCol << ", bottom-left point row: "
          << bottomLeftRow << std::endl;
```

If you are not sure that the edge intersects the top and left side of the image, use `cv::findNonZero` on the full `edge` image instead, which may be less predictable in some situations:

```
cv::Mat im, edge, locs;
im = cv::imread("./lBnUO.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Canny(im, edge, 0.0, 255.0);
cv::findNonZero(edge, locs);
int topRightCol = (locs.at<cv::Point>(0)).x;
int bottomLeftRow = (locs.at<cv::Point>(locs.rows-1)).y;
std::cout << "Top-right point column: " << topRightCol << ", bottom-left point row: " 
          << bottomLeftRow << std::endl;
```

For the image provided here, both codes above will print out:

```
Top-right point column: 190, bottom-left point row: 160
```